# How may I run multiple Tor relay instances in a single Windows 7 machine?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, relays

How may I run multiple Tor relay instances in a single Windows 7 machine? 
And if you can tell-me step-by-step, I appreciate a lot of!!

Comment: use srvany.exe. here is the clue : http://x.pv8.us/net-tech/how-to-run-tor-as-a-service-in-windows.html